# Adding Start-up package and yearly funding to CV?

Tags: cv, job, tenure-track

I am an assistant professor at an Institution that provided me with a continuous yearly funding plus a start-up funding package. The values are substantial.
Is it common practice to add these values to your acquired funding in your CV?
Would this be perceived as unnecessary or as a show-off?
Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A demonstrated ability to acquire funding is often a requirement for an academic position, so it should absolutely be added to your CV. Stating the amount (or other details) of the funding package is a way to clearly state the facts, which is also highly desirable on a CV.

The whole idea of a CV is to "show off" your achievements and there is no reason you should be reluctant to add any of them.

Comment: But if a start-up package and a baseline funding are taken for granted at the given institution I am at, should I still add them to my CV? Every other assistant professor will have the similar funding levels, I suppose.

Comment: You never know who reads your CV, and if they are aware of this fact. So I would advise to add the information.